# displaying data from table columns in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to display information from my table for the user who submitted the data. I can't seem to setup how to display ALL users information from the table.

index.html.erb:

```
#This gives undefined local variable or method 'bio'. bio.content works on the user page if signed in and shows data from the user only.

<%= bio.content.all %>
```

bio_controller.rb:

```
            def show
            @bio= User.all
        end
```

user_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @bio = current_user.bio.build
```

Can someone help show me what exactly I am missing so that I can show all bio information from the database, instead of only being allowed to show data of the signed in user from their profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@bio.content.all` in the view. And you probably want to structure it with some HTML:

```
if @bio
   @bio.content.all.each do |b|
      <!-- some HTML to show the `b` record -->
   end
end
```

Comment: That gives a undefined method 'content' for nil. Content is my database table name name, do I have to define it in the bio controller under def show? I have tried a few different lines for it this morning.

Comment: issue is perhaps in my routes. Will tweak it some to see if I can find the solution.

Comment: @xps15z your post indicates you set `@bio`. If it's possible it is empty, then you can just do a check for nil. If there's other "business logic" around when it's empty or not, you'll need to reveal that for a more elaborate answer. Right now, you only have a few tiny pieces of code showing. :)